# How to allow only one user to edit a Parse object?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, permissions

I'm creating an app that allows co-workers to upload shifts (objects) to Parse that they need covered. I save all the shifts to a "Shifts" class (in the data browser). I want to restrict the ALC so that only the person who uploaded the shift/object can edit it (everyone can "read" it). Is there a way that I can create/upload that programmatically (rather than having to go into the Data Browser and add it manually)?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a relationship between your Shifts and your existing _User table. If you add a shift, you can create a relationship to the `_User` table. Than, if you retrieve the info, you can check if the user who reads the record is also the one who created it by comparing the active `PFUser.currentUser` with the user from your shift.

```
//Initial safe
var user = PFUser.currentUser
var relation = user.relationForKey("shifts")
relation.addObject(yourShiftObject)
user.saveInBackground()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ACL on objects when you create them. The best would be to define a default ACL that allows the creating user to read and write the object while still allowing public read access.

Example taken from the documentation

```
var defaultACL = PFACL.ACL()
// Optionally enable public read access while disabling public write access.
defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true)
PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser:true)
```

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#security-recommendations/iOS